# Visual C++ - header of my static library not found

Tags: c++, static-libraries, header-files

I'm trying to make my own static library, but I can't use it in my another project. I compiled the library in command prompt with this command:

```
cl /c /EHsc Matrix3.cpp
```

I added it as a reference to my project, and I added the directory containing the compiled .lib file to my project.

The library code is below.

Header file:

```
#pragma once

typedef struct
{
    float m[3][3];
} matrix3;

class Matrix3
{
public:
    Matrix3();
    ~Matrix3();
    matrix3* MatrixAdd(matrix3* A, matrix3* B);
    matrix3* ScalarMatrixMul(float scalar, matrix3* A);
    matrix3* MatrixMult(matrix3* A, matrix3* B);
};
```

.cpp file:

```
#include "Matrix3.h"

Matrix3::Matrix3() {
}


Matrix3::~Matrix3() {
}

matrix3* Matrix3::MatrixAdd(matrix3* A, matrix3* B) {

    matrix3* result = new matrix3;

    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
            result->m[row][col] = A->m[row][col] + B->m[row][col];

    return result;
}

matrix3* Matrix3::ScalarMatrixMul(float scalar, matrix3* A) {

    matrix3* result = new matrix3;

    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
            result->m[row][col] = scalar * A->m[row][col];

    return result;
}

matrix3* Matrix3::MatrixMult(matrix3* A, matrix3* B) {

    matrix3* result = new matrix3;

    float sum;

    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                sum += A->m[row][k] * B->m[k][col];
            result->m[row][col] = sum;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Using pointers is a poor design, it forces the user to worry about memory management, and makes it much harder for the compiler to optimize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your other project settings, in *C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories* you need to specify directory where `Matrix3.h` is placed. Otherwise compiler will search in the same directory where the source file being compiled is placed.